# JSON.Stringify | Output the result on the screen with quote tags ''

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, stringify

I am using the following methods in my React App to transform my `Object` to string. Everything works fine, but I want to output the result on the screen without `""` around the output.

```
  renderConfigInfoCellRow = configInfoKey => {
    const { lconfigInfo } = this.props;
    return (
      <tr key={configInfoKey}>
        <td className="pt-3 text-muted font-weight-bold w-25">{configInfoKey}</td>
        {(typeof lconfigInfo.sql[configInfoKey] === 'string' && (
          <td className="pt-3">{JSON.stringify(lconfigInfo.sql[configInfoKey])}</td>
        )}
      </tr>
    );
  };
```

And I am using it here:

```
<tbody>
  {Object.keys(lconfigInfo.sql).map(configInfoKey =>
    this.renderConfigInfoCellRow(configInfoKey)
  )}
</tbody>
```

Any idea of how to remove the `""` surrounding the `"output"` ?? Or if they is an alternative to JSON.Stringify. Thank you!!

Comment: Could you please provide as well the Object output example? And what's the actual result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no sense to use JSON.stringify(), if data is not object, try to change
this `JSON.stringify(lconfigInfo.sql[configInfoKey])`
to `lconfigInfo.sql[configInfoKey]`.

Also there is condition where you check does the `lconfigInfo.sql[configInfoKey]` is string and trying to transform it again to string.

Answer (score 1):

`JSON.stringify` outputs valid JSON, so if you pass it a string it will return a string wrapped with `""`.

You're checking if the value of `lconfigInfo.sql[configInfoKey]` is a string so you can just print it out directly like:

```
<td className="pt-3">{lconfigInfo.sql[configInfoKey]}</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `.replace(/\"/g, "")`:

```
{JSON.stringify(lconfigInfo.sql[configInfoKey]).replace(/\"/g, "")}
```